# Moving item on ItemAdded gives Error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, development, event-receivers, events

IN my event receiver, on Item Added event I have placed my custom method to move document based on a rule.
The issue is when a document is uploaded in the Upload dialog I get an error
saying item not available.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   [FileNotFoundException:
>   0x80070002]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndFolderProperties(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrStartUrl, ListDocsFlags ListDocsFlags, Boolean
>   bThrowException, Int32& phrStatus, Object& pvarFiles, Object&
>   pvarDirs, UInt32& pdwNumberOfFiles, UInt32& pdwNumberOfDirs) +0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndFolderProperties(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrStartUrl, ListDocsFlags ListDocsFlags, Boolean
>   bThrowException, Int32& phrStatus, Object& pvarFiles, Object&
>   pvarDirs, UInt32& pdwNumberOfFiles, UInt32& pdwNumberOfDirs) +40768117
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetFileOrFolderProperties(String strUrl,
>   ListDocsFlags listDocsFlags, Boolean throwException,
>   SPBasePermissions& permMask) +173
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.PropertiesCore(Boolean throwException)
>   +101    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile.get_Length() +11    Mirosoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.UploadPage.OnSubmit(Object o,
>   EventArgs e) +2506    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3804

Tried the below code in the ItemAdded method after executin my custom method

```
properties.ErrorMessage = "Item moved to the target library";
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError;
```

But still I get the error even though the file is successfully moved to the destination library as I needed. How can I prevent this error ?

Comment: The error is being thrown from upload page. I think its better to do this via a Workflow rather even reciever.

Comment: I've already seen this behavior, and if I remember correctly it happens in SP2013 and not in SP2010...  
The point is that the code of the Upload page deals with the `SPFile` after `ItemAdded` has run (witch is in my opinion a design error from MS).  
Trying with an async `ItemAdded` may only give you the same error on a random basis...
Maybe a job, or an ER on check-in?

Comment: Can you post you event receiver code? I have a hunch that disabling event firing in your code before you perform this operation might help?

Comment: Thanks all for the replies @Evariste it happens in ItemUpdated as well since I delete the file. The thing is i dynamically bind event receivers to document libraries. What's an ER ? Can a workflow be binded to library dynamically so that it will move the file. I need to move the file immediately when uploaded. I'm trying to create the DropOff library functionality in SharePoint Foundation. I don't think customizing the edit form will b a good idea. What do you think ?

Comment: ER = event receiver. Yes, a workflow can be trigerred when a file is added to the library. But Im not keen of WF in such scenarios: they're slow, buggy, and they're visible in the UI. However, I don't have a better ready-to-go solution for you at the moment.

Comment: @Arsalan I was refering this post http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Disable-Events-from-Firing-on-SharePoint-2013. But didn't work out may be because I'm deleting the file. I even tried this.EventFiringEnabled = false; but no luck

Comment: @Evariste well I came up with a work around for the moment. Invoked a asynch method within the `ItemAdded()`. In it, the SP file is deleted after a 2 seconds delay. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Content Organizer feature to route documents to the appropriate location instead of using custom code?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2013 Foundation. Unfortunately the feature is not there